# How to use express middlewares in express-coffee

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

So I am trying to use [express-coffee](https://github.com/twilson63/express-coffee) together with [express-form](https://github.com/freewil/express-form) middleware and I am following the proposed controller structure.

In channels.coffee (controller) I have

```
module.exports =
    ..
    create: (req, res)->
      form(
        filter('title')
          .trim()
          .required()
      )
      console.log 'after filter'
      if form.isValid
        console.log 'isValid'
      else
        console.log req.form.title
      console.log req.form.title
      res.send 'finished'
```

In the end, this doesn't intercept the action, like it should. How would you wire express middleware to actions in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the middleware from within your handler, whereas it should be used as an argument to the route.

In JS, it would look like this:

```
var channels = require('./channels');
app.get('/', form(...), channels.create);
```

If you want to keep the middleware and your handler together, you could try this (still JS, my CS is at best rusty ;):

```
// channels.js
module.exports = {
  create : [ form(...), function(req, res) {
  }]
};
// app.js
var channels = require('./channels');
app.get('/', channels.create);
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to move this into channels.create?